# How to view how a plain-text email client displays PHPMailer's AltBody?

Tags: email, phpmailer, plaintext

I'm using PHPMailer and I'd like to see how the plain-text AltBody is appearing in clients that only support plain text. What is the easiest way to do this? (echoing $mail->AltBody does not work)

Answer (score 3):

In Thunderbird you can do this with **View->Message Body As-> Plain Text**.

See [Testing the plain text version of your email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2520/testing-the-plain-text-version)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test this in GMail, click on "Message Text Garbled?" in the drop down menu next to the reply button. This will show you the content of PHPMailer's AltBody.

Comment: Sadly, this answer seems obsolete.  GMail no longer provides that option.  You can look at the message source by selecting "Show Original", but that doesn't display the plain text as a client would.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @jason-george's answer:  To test with GMail and Thunderbird

1. Download and install the [Thunderbird mail client](https://www.thunderbird.net/).
2. In GMail, find the message you want to test.  Select the 3-button menu and select "Download message".
3. Start Thunderbird. Cancel out of any start-up wizards and account setup screens.
4. In the file menu, select to "Open saved message". Navigate to the message you saved in step 2 and open it. (You may have to again cancel out of an account setup wizard.)
5. The message will open, usually in full HTML mode.  Under the view Menu select "Message Body As..." and select "Plain Text".  You will see the plain-text version.